# What is an E symbol in a document?

Tags: dart

While studying Dart, I encountered the following document.

[Dart SDK](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Iterable/map.html)

```
Iterable<T> map<T>(
  T f(
       E e
      )
)
```

What is the E symbol?

- T -> type variables for generic
- e -> expression
- f -> function

Best regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Iterable`](https://api.dartlang.org/dev/2.0.0-dev.69.5/dart-core/Iterable-class.html) has a single generic parameter `E` which is the type of items it iterates over.  In the `map` method, the Iterable provides each item type `E` to a function `f` which accepts an `E` and returns a `T`, where `T` is the type of the items in the new Iterable.  For example:

```
// A List<int> implements Iterable<int>
Iterable<int> numbers = <int>[1, 2, 3, 4];

// A method which creates a String from an int.
String makeStringFromNumber(int number) {
  return number.toString();
}
// T = String              E = int    F = int -> String
Iterable<String> strings = numbers.map(makeStringFromNumber);
```